# IIS 7 issue with display:inline?

Tags: html, css, iis

Sorry, our dev web server isn't outwards facing so I can provide a link, but here is what's happening.

I'm doing markup for a new website and writing it on my local machine.  Everything looks fine there, BUT once it's running on IIS, a UL on which I have styled the LI items to display:inline are still being displayed vertically instead of in a horizontal row.  Is this a common occurrence?  It's happening in all browsers EXCEPT firefox.  The source code when I'm browsing on my local machine is EXACTLY the same as what you see when you view source off the IIS machine.

That being said, is there a better way to accomplish what I need here?  I have to have 2 rows of three DIV or SPAN tags each.  Each contains a thumbnail image, then two rows of text underneath.  All three items in each tag will need to be centered horizontally.

Comment: I'll have to chop it up and anonymize it because of business policy.  Give me a few.

Comment: IIS has nothing to do with rendering HTML.

Comment: Well, then, what's the disparity between loading the exact same HTML and CSS on my local machine versus it being delivered through IIS?  I've run multiple compares on both the source files as well as generated source in the browsers and they are byte by byte exactly the same, but render differently.  Same instance of IE 8, two different tabs.  One pointed to file://myHTML and one to http://dev/myHTML.

Comment: The code is too long to paste :/

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer is that there is some stylesheet that exists on your webserver but not on your local machine which is overriding your CSS rules for your ULs. Have you used a tool like Firebug to see if this is the case?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the UL. Here is the CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    li {list-style:none}
    ul {display:inline}
</style>
```

...and the HTML:

```
<li>
  <ul>Home</ul>
  <ul>About</ul>
</li>
```